# How do I get the onclick to go to the getCookie function?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is that when you press the button it runs the getCookie function, but why doesn't it work?

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" id="disbtn" onclick="getCookie(usertxt)">Say</button>
<h1 id="txt11">hej</h1>
<h1 id="txt22">hej2</h1>
<script>
function getCookie(usertxt)
{
  var say1 = usertxt;
  document.getElementById("txt11").innerHTML=say1;
  document.getElementById("txt22").innerHTML=say2;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put usertxt into quotes

```
<button type="button" id="disbtn" onclick="getCookie('usertxt')">Say</button>
```

Than it will work!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your 'usertxt' variable is not defined anywhere in your code. What is the goal of your getCookie function?
Could you elaborate so that we can understand better what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your HTML To

```
<button type="button" id="disbtn" onclick="getCookie(' My text')">Say</button>
<h1 id="txt11">hej</h1>
<h1 id="txt22">hej2</h1>`
```

Or Use `onclick="getCookie('usertxt')"`  Wrap usertxt in quotes.

And in JS  You need to declare say2 variable also.

Change JS to

```
function getCookie(usertxt)
{
  var say1 = usertxt;
  var say2 = ' dd dsa '
  document.getElementById("txt11").innerHTML=say1;
  document.getElementById("txt22").innerHTML=say2;
}
```

Comment: Do I have to make another getCookie fucntion or can I do it in the usertxt function?

Comment: No you don't need to create another function. You need to correct errors in your existing code.